# SVG text getComputedTextLength too short for Arabic font

Tags: html, css, fonts, arabic

I am trying to add a specific font to a web application for Arabic text in SVG. The font looks fine but getComputedTextLength() returns results that are "too short" i.e. the text takes up more space than it should when rendered. This causes problems when attempting to wrap text etc..

Anyone know a workaround or fix? I have tried a couple of different fonts and get the same result in Chrome and Firefox.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo&display=swap&subset=arabic" rel="stylesheet">`

https://www.google.com/get/noto/#kufi-arab

`@font-face {
  font-family: 'NotoKufiArabic';
  src: url('../font/NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`

Sample d3 code that is giving "too short" results:

```
    legend.append("text")
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.label)})
        .each(function(d) { d.legendWidth = this.getComputedTextLength() + 24 });
```

The 24 is just some padding. The legendWidth is too small. I tried applying a factor e.g. 1.4 but that doesn't fix all cases. This works perfectly if I don't try use a specific Arabic font.

Comment: Can you show the an example of the code so we can reproduce this?

Comment: Sure. I just added a sample.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening. The chart code calls getComputedTextLength() before the Arabic font has been loaded and the width is computed for the narrower fallback font. Then the font loads and the text elements suddenly get a lot bigger but my JS code doesn't run.